# Customizing Image Edit in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

I'm developing a WP Plugin that allows to add effects to images. The JS part has been completed, but I would like to simplify the user experience adding to the visual editor (tinymce) a modal window that allows users to select their preferred effects and settings.
I would like that once selected the effect and settings, some attribute are added into the img tag.
The ideal solution is to extend the image edit window. I've tried to figured out how to customize it, but I'm afraid it's not possible (you can only show custom fields when you add a new media but not into the editing window).
Another approach is to add a context menu that opens a standalone window, but I don't know how to do it and how to interact with tinymce.
Is there a way to do it? Can you suggest me a tutorial, a plugin to analyze or any other resource? Any idea would be appreciated.

Thank you
T

Comment: hello I'm trying to figure out the same thing: how to customize wordpress image edit pages? have you got some clue since you asked the question? I'll let you know if I find out something useful

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code the add effects and it is done using applets.It may Help u out

/* Arpana */

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ConvolveApp extends JFrame {
  CPanel displayPanel;

  JButton sharpenButton, blurringButton, edButton, resetButton;

  public ConvolveApp() {
    super();
    Container container = getContentPane();

    displayPanel = new CPanel();
    container.add(displayPanel);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    panel
        .setBorder(new TitledBorder(
            "Click a Button to Perform the Associated Operation and Reset..."));

    sharpenButton = new JButton("Sharpen");
    sharpenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    blurringButton = new JButton("Blur");
    blurringButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    edButton = new JButton("Edge Detect");
    edButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel.add(sharpenButton);
    panel.add(blurringButton);
    panel.add(edButton);
    panel.add(resetButton);

    container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
     //setSize(100,100);
    setSize(displayPanel.getWidth()+50, displayPanel.getHeight() );
    setVisible(true); 
  }
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new ConvolveApp();
  }

  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

      if (button.equals(sharpenButton)) {
        displayPanel.sharpen();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(blurringButton)) {
        displayPanel.blur();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(edButton)) {
        displayPanel.edgeDetect();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(resetButton)) {
        displayPanel.reset();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      }
    }
  }
}

class CPanel extends JLabel {
  Image displayImage;

  BufferedImage biSrc;

  BufferedImage biDest; // Destination image is mandetory.

  BufferedImage bi; // Only an additional reference.

  Graphics2D big;

  CPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.black);
    loadImage();
    setSize(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getWidth(this)); 
    createBufferedImages();
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void loadImage() {
    displayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Appu.jpg");
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    mt.addImage(displayImage, 1);
    try {
      mt.waitForAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception while loading.");
    }
    if (displayImage.getWidth(this) == -1) {
      System.out.println("No jpg file");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public void createBufferedImages() {
    biSrc = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    big = biSrc.createGraphics();
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);

    biDest = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  }

  public void sharpen() {
    float data[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 9.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void blur() {
    float data[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f,
        0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

    public void edgeDetect() {
    float data[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f };

    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);

    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void reset() {
    big.setColor(Color.black);
    big.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this));
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    paintComponent(g);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```